# Can't find 'Convert to Android system permissions' and 'Infer Annotations' under Analyse menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I want to use the new tools android-studio 2.2 has to offer :

1. Convert to Android system permissions
2. Infer Annotations

However, i can't see those tools in the menu. 
I've tried restart, selecting other files, selecting the whole project, but - no luck so far - i still not able to see those entries in the menu.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1
Build #AI-145.2878421, built on May 17, 2016

I've been folowing the guide on the official site : http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/
and the [i/o guide (the tools are described at around the time 21:00)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1334&v=csaXml4xtN8)

[image: analyse menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Convert to android system permission**
At [21:45](https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?t=21m45s) he says "This is still a work in progress". The feature is not done yet, therefore you cannot find it in the IDE.

**Infer annotations**
At [21:10](https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?t=21m10s) he says that this functionality is behind "a flag". It is unclear which flag, or how to enable it.

It is also discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4k8lqf/infer_annotations_in_android_studio/) on reddit, but no conclusive results yet.

The experimental thing they mention there is not related to these 
features.

---

I waited for the release of 2.2 preview 2, but they are not in there either.
It can be safely assumed that both these features will be released with future versions of android studio.